How do I set a custom aspect ratio in ClipChamp?
I am editing footage from a Steam Deck with an aspect ratio of 16:10 in the video editor ClipChamp. However, the only aspect ratio options I see in are 16:9, 9:16, 1:1, 4:5, 2:3, and 21:9.
How do I set a custom aspect ratio of 16:10 in ClipChamp?

ClipChamp does not allow custom aspect ratios. You could create and edit the video in ClipChamp and export it, and then run ffmpeg to rescale/resize it, or you can use a different video editor which does support alternate aspect ratios.
To scale using ffmpeg you'd need to zoom in on the exported ClipChamp video, otherwise you'd have black bars at the top and bottom, or the image would be stretched vertically. Also, you WILL lose some fidelity doing this, due to the necessary zoom.
Alternatively, use a tool such as the free DaVinci Resolve video editing software, which is a more complex product, but has a "basic" mode in its main tab and the ability to set the aspect ratio to anything you please.
